# Is this problem a front-running or race-condition or something else?

Tags: contract-design, bug, frontrunning, audit

What is the correct name of this problem in audit terms?

If I have a contract that sells NFTs. The address with the most NTFs has a very high chance to win a prize.

The problem is that 1 address can buy all/most the NFTs by sending transactions with high fees that are executed quicker by validators than other buyers. What do you call this in Audit terms?

It sounds like front-running or race-condition to me. However, the attacker does not wait to see a transaction of other buyers in the pending pool and then front run it. The attacker waits for the event that the purchase has started and then reacts quickly and sends transactions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to fit in the class of "mechanism design".

For fixing the mechanism in this specific NFT example, some solutions can be to increase the number of NFTs, or adjust the logic of "very high chance to win" (for example, if buying 10x more NFTs only gives 1% more chance to win, do you think someone would still do it?).

Another related problem, not so much in this current NFT example, can be described as First Come First Serve (FCFS).